# WordPress Conditionally Load Files

Tags: wordpress

I am building a WP Multisite network. Each site uses the same theme. 
I want to create a Testimonials custom post type. But, I only want to load it on one site.
I am including the custom post type php file within the functions.php file, this loads it onto every site in the network.

How can I get this to only load on one site? Via conditional statement of some sort?

Any advice/tips would be grateful.

Huw

Comment: I would have created a plugin that loads the Custom Post Type and activated it on that single site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my answer from the comment. This is how you can make a CPT with a plugin.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Your Custom Post Type
Description: Add a custom post type
Author: Oskar Hane
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://oskarhane.com
*/


// Register Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'registerMyCustomPostType' );
function registerMyCustomPostType()
{
    $labels_cpt = array(
        'name' => _x('My Posts', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('My Post', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add new', 'kurser'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit item'),
        'new_item' => __('New item'),
        'view_item' => __('View item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search items' ),
        'not_found' =>  __('No items found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No items in trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
          );

    register_post_type('my_post_type', array(
        'labels' => $labels_cpt,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor')
    ));   
}
?>
```

Just activate it for the network and then install/activate it for the site you want it.

And make sure to check all the values, especially `'supports' =>` so you get all the fields you want.

Comment: That looks like an excellent idea. I haven't created a plugin before; this looks simple. Thanks

Comment: @HuwRowlands It's easy, just upload to your plugin dir and you'll see it in the plugin list in admin. Please mark my answer as the correct one and upvote it if it helped you :)